# jQuery conflicts of many scripts

Tags: php, jquery

I am asking my question after I have tried many ways to solve it but i couldn't.
I have conflicts with jQuery scripts in my site.  The other I have changed the $ to jQuery and they worked but this script didn't work for me.

This code below works only the second script but the first script no.

```
<script defer="defer">
jquery.noConflict();
(function ($) {
    $("#insured_list").tablesorterPager({
        container: jquery("#pager")
    });

})(jQuery);
</script>
<script defer="defer">
(function ($) {
    $("#insured_list").tablesorter({
        widthFixed: true,
        widgets: ['zebra']
    })
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

before it was like that

```
<script defer="defer">
$(document).ready(function()


        $("#insured_list").tablesorterPager({container: jquery("#pager")}); 
                          .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})
});
```

and neither worked, no page script no sorter.
I tried noconflict but it didnt seem to work.

Comment: Your formatting is messed up. Revise the question.

Comment: I have fixed the syntax erorr at your code: http://jsfiddle.net/BaNX8/3/. Still, I don't know what you're trying: You don't need `.noConflict` for this bit of code. Instead of using `defer`, use `$(document).ready(function(){/* Code to be executed when the page has loaded here. */})`.

Comment: i have added the edited script <script>
(function($) {
  
    $(function(){
        $("#insured_list")
        
        .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});
        $("#insured_list")
        .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']})
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>  but its the same , oredering working but pagination not working

Comment: Can you post the complete output html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a variable as follows :

```
$s = jquery.noConflict();
```

And then replace all $ of a part of code with $s

Hopefully it will work

Comment: you mean in all js files ? i replaced in the code in php file . but didnt work

Comment: You are getting conflicts, because you are using two libraries together . So, you need to replace just any one of them, not all. If you are using libX and libY, then replace variables of any onelibrary, not BOTH

Comment: ok i done like that : i changed the first code above : <script defer="defer">
var $s = jquery.noConflict();

jquery.noConflict();
(function($s) { 
  

        $s("#insured_list")
  
  .tablesorterPager({container: $s("#pager")}); 
  
})(jQuery);

</script> and replaced as you said in the file tablesorterPager

Comment: remove jquery.noConflict(); in 3rd line

Comment: also undo jquery by $s or $ as required as you mentioned in the question

Comment: undo jquery by $ or $s as you mentioned in the question

Comment: you mean like that ? var $s = jquery.noConflict();


(function(jquery) { 
  

        jquery("#insured_list")
  
  .tablesorterPager({container: jquery("#pager")}); 
  
})(jQuery);  ----------didnt work

Comment: You mentioned in the question, that you have replaced jquery by $s, I said to undo that. Remove all jquery

Comment: Please check for similar errors. Friend, it always works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jquery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //Your code using $
});
```

Comment: Just to verify, it's jQuery.noConflict() and not jquery.noConflict();